# Skip with if condition in mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to skip some data if my condition becomes true. Can I use if condition inside skip? Or can I put skip inside if condition in an aggregate method?
For example 
I want to use `db.article.aggregate( { $skip : 5 } );` this skip with if condition

Comment: What's the condition? Can you please give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

Does "skip if my condition becomes true" means that you want to match values "not in"? In this case just use the $nin operator, example from mongodb [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)

```
db.inventory.find( { qty: { $nin: [ 5, 15 ] } } )
```

Comment: No that was not exactly what I want. I want to use `db.article.aggregate(
    { $skip : 5 }
);` this skip with if condition. Thank you @Simonluca

Comment: Will be useful to know which is the condition... btw, you are thinking in terms of "if this than that", but in an aggregation you should think in terms of "transformation of data", using $match, $project, $group etc..

Comment: Yeah It is true. I want to use like If true then skip otherwise I don't want to skip.